# Distance from origin (start-patch) to center of in-radius cluster of turtles in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have determined the maximum number of turtles within clusters of turtles dispersed across a world in Netlogo such that the largest number of turtles (within said radius) derived for all turtles is the result (assigned to a variable).

```
  let corr-peak-density max [count neighbors in-radius 50] of turtles
```

However, I am now trying to get the distance from the origin (start-patch) of the world to this largest cluster of turtles or neighbors and failing at it. Ideally, if I can write code find the distance from the origin of the world to the turtle or patch at the center of the maximum-sized turtle-cluster yielded by the in-radius function, it would be best. But, my attempts so fair have failed. Kindly help with the following line of code (or some other preferred way) to achieve this.

```
    let corr-peak-density-distance [distance start-patch] of patch[corr-peak-density]
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong in the ensuing line of code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the code `count neighbors in-radius 50` is incorrect. `neighbors` will report the 8 patches surrounding the turtle. Since all 8 of these patches are within 50 of the turtle, this code will *always* report 8. Instead, you want `count turtles in-radius 50`. It's worth noting though that this code will likely be quite slow. You might try `count turtles with [ distance myself < 50 ]` instead. It does essentially the same thing, but should be faster when using such a large radius.

Next, instead of calculating just the peak density, let's get the turtle at the center of that cluster:

```
let peak-density-turtle max-one-of turtles [ count turtles with [ distance myself < 50 ] ]
let corr-peak-density [ count turtles with [ distance myself < 50 ] ] of peak-density-turtle
```

Then, getting the distance from this turtle to the starting patch is simple:

```
let corr-peak-density-distance [ distance start-patch ] of peak-density-turtle
```

Comment: Kindly see the question I posted and the response at the following link: [How do you implement code for distance-based mortality for each turtles in Netlogo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146656/distance-based-mortality-model-in-netlogo/44160714#44160714). I would appreciate your expertise if you can.