# Distance-based mortality model in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am calculating cumulative turtle mortality in netlogo as a function of distance moved by turtles (100 of them) from the origin (`start-patch`) in the netlogo interface world. In the code below the '`Pass-Away`' procedure is linked to a global interface switch called "space-death" which when switched on yields said distance-based mortality undertaken by the procedure called "`Pass-Away-Space`", otherwise maintains regular per-time-step (`tick`) mortality undertaken by the procedure called "`Pass-Away-Time`":

```
    to Pass-Away-Time
  ask turtles [
    let chances 1 - exp( -1 * mortality * ticks )
    if chances >= 1 [die
      set dead-count dead-count + 1
    ]
  ]
end

to Pass-Away-Space
  ask turtles [
  let chances 1 - exp( -1 * mortality * [distance start-patch] of turtles)
    if chances >= 1 [die
      set dead-count dead-count + 1
    ]
  ]
end

to Pass-Away
  ask turtles [
     ifelse space-death [
     Pass-Away-Space][ 
     Pass-Away-Time
     ]
   ]
end
```

I get two errors doing this, both likely due to issues with the coding of the "`Pass-Away-Space`" procedure. The first is *Only the observer can ASK the set of all turtles.* Then when I move the `let chances 1 - exp( -1 * mortality * [distance start-patch] of turtles)` outside of the `ask turtles[]` brackets this error is resolved only yield another that says ** expected input to be a number but got the list* followed by a sequence of numbers. Perhaps due to the fact that the section of the mortality equation that reads `* [distance start-patch] of turtles` is invoked for multiple turtles (which is exactly what I want to achieve - have each random-walking turtle use its distance from the origin to calculate its cumulative per-step mortality and die above a threshold - an event that occurs at different times for different turtles at different distances).  Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The first error is because you are asking all turtles to ask all turtles. Starting with your `Pass-Away` procedure and assuming `space-death` is set to TRUE. What happens? You ask all turtles to run the `Pass-Away-Space` procedure. That is, each turtle will run that procedure in turn. The first step of that procedure is to `ask turtles [ ]`. So a turtle is asking all turtles to do something. Hence the error.

To fix it, you need to rewrite the `Pass-Away-Space` procedure so it runs whatever code needs to be run for a SINGLE turtle (and similarly for `Pass-Away-Time`). You probably want something like:

```
to Pass-Away-Space
  if exp( -1 * mortality * [distance start-patch]) < 0
  [ die
    set dead-count dead-count + 1
  ]
end
```

Comment: thanks for your thoughts, I was able to figure that out so I rewrote both Pass-Away-Space and Pass-Away-Time without ask turtle. That got rid of the first error (*Only the observer can ASK the set of all turtles*) stated in my question, but the second error remained an issue (** expected input to be a number but got the list**). The issue with the following line of code: `let chances 1 - exp( -1 * mortality * [distance start-patch] of turtles`.

Comment: You changed this line of code to `if exp( -1 * mortality * [distance start-patch]) < 0`. In order to understand you correctly, do you indicate that the change resolves the issue and works such that each turtle calculates  its distance from the origin (`start-patch`), then uses that to calculate its mortality?

Comment: no, I have no idea what start-patch is in your code. I rewrote the code only to fix the error that I discussed, about nested ask turtles. SO protocol is to ask separate questions for multiple problems because the site is intended to be helpful to other people with similar problems, not just fix yours. So please create a question with a title that is specifically about your problem and show the code you now have.

Comment: that literally is all the code I have ... start-patch is the origin (the point (x,y) - (0,0) in the world. and i posted both concerns (having to do with the same code) in my original question. It appears to me that you may have answered one and either forgot about or did not see the other!

Comment: so, you want us to answer a question that you can't be bothered writing? You have now stated that the code you provided is not the code that has the problem. Also, there is no way this is complete because `start-patch` is nowhere defined in your code. Please write a proper question that has the code you have the problem with and the error that is being produced. That way, we won't have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

So the first issue here is the nested use of the `ask turtles [ ... ]` command, which we can disambiguate by removing it from the `to Pass-Away` procedure or alternatively, from both of the other two (preceding) functions nested within it, as seen below (demonstrating the later of the aforementioned means.

```
let start-patch patch 0 0
to Pass-Away-Time
  ask turtles [
    let chances 1 - exp( -1 * mortality * ticks )
    if chances >= 1 [die
      set dead-count dead-count + 1
    ]
  ]
end

to Pass-Away-Space
  ask turtles [
  ; let chances 1 - exp( -1 * mortality * [distance start-patch] of turtles)
  let chances 1 - exp( -1 * mortality * (distance start-patch))
    if chances >= 1 [die
      set dead-count dead-count + 1
    ]
  ]
end

to Pass-Away
   ifelse space-death [
     Pass-Away-Space][ 
     Pass-Away-Time
  ]
end
```

The second error can be resolved by switching the line of code commented (`;`) out in the `to Pass-Away-Space` procedure withe the immediate succeeding line so that when each turtle attempts to execute `chances`, cumulative per-distance (from origin) mortality is not calculated as an array of turtle chances with the use of the `[distance start-patch] of turtles` command, but rather per individual turtle with `(distance start-patch)` whenever the procedure is called by the nesting `to Pass-Away` procedure.